# How can I write variables inside the tasks file in ansible

Tags: ansible

I have this *play.yml*

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
    
  tasks:
    - include: apache.yml
```

My *apache.yml* file looks like this:

```yaml
vars:
  url: http://example.com/apache
    
- name: Download apache
  shell: wget {{ url }}
```

This is giving me an error.

If I remove `vars` then it works. But, I want to keep the variable inside the included tasks file, so that I can keep different variables for different tasks separate.

Answer (score 96):

**NOTE:** Using `set_fact` as described below sets a fact/variable onto the remote servers that the task is running against. This fact/variable will then persist across subsequent tasks for the entire duration of your playbook.

Also, these facts are immutable (for the duration of the playbook), and cannot be changed once set.

---

#### ORIGINAL ANSWER

Use `set_fact` before your task to set *facts* which seem interchangeable with variables:

```
- name: Set Apache URL
  set_fact:
    apache_url: 'http://example.com/apache'

- name: Download Apache
  shell: wget {{ apache_url }}
```

See http://docs.ansible.com/set_fact_module.html for the official word.

Comment: It seems to be a better solution since you can use the fact as a variable.

Comment: Note this subtle difference compared with variables:  _This module allows setting new variables. Variables are set on a host-by-host basis just like facts discovered by the setup module. **These variables will survive between plays.**_

Comment: Sidenote: it seems, that you can't change a variable in place using `set_fact`... so if the the name is already taken by a variable it won't modify that... which can be error prone to setting a variable to the same name on a higher level of a playbook. So be sure you won't do that (e.g. use a potentially unique name for example, not 'item').

Comment: Note on your note... `Also, these facts are immutable (for the duration of the playbook), and cannot be changed once set.` -- This isn't strictly true. You can overwrite a fact created with `set_fact` in an earlier task, you just can't overwrite a variable set in any other way... As an example, if you loop through a set of tasks, and at the start of each loop iteration you use `set_fact: loop_item='{{ item }}'`, then use `debug: msg='{{ loop_item }}'`, you'll see the *fact* changes with each loop iteration.

Answer (score 90):

Just move the variable definition inside inside your task:

```yaml
- name: Download apache
  shell: wget {{ url }}
  vars:
    url: http://example.com/apache
```

Answer (score 14):

Variable definitions are meant to be used in tasks. But if you want to include them in tasks probably use the `register` directive. Like this:

```
- name: Define variable in task.
  shell: echo "http://www.my.url.com"
  register: url

- name: Download apache
  shell: wget {{ item }}
  with_items: url.stdout
```

You can also look at [roles](http://docs.ansible.com/playbooks_roles.html#roles) as a way of separating tasks depending on the different roles [roles](http://docs.ansible.com/playbooks_roles.html#roles). This way you can have separate variables for each of one of your roles.  For example you may have a `url` variable for `apache1` and a separate `url` variable for the role `apache2`.

Comment: I thought register only worked with output from a command? How can I make a static variable in a role's `roles/<role>/tasks/main.yml` ?

Comment: @ThorSummoner you mean this like a regular variable?  http://docs.ansible.com/playbooks_variables.html#variables-defined-in-a-playbook  and maybe this?  http://docs.ansible.com/playbooks_roles.html#role-default-variables

Comment: This solution is a total overkill. U send the var value over ssh to the remote host then retrieve it back, to use it locally on the control node!!

Answer (score 6):

In Your example, apache.yml is tasklist, but not playbook

In depends on desired architecture, You can do one of:

**1. Convert apache.yml to role.** Then define tasks in roles/apache/tasks/mail.yml and variables in roles/apache/defaults/mail.yml (vars in defaults can be overriden when role applied)

play.yml :

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  sudo: false

  roles:
     - apache
```

roles/apache/defaults/main.yml :

```
---
url: czxcxz
```

roles/apache/tasks/main.yml :

```
---
- name: Download apache
  shell: wget {{url}}
```

**2. Set vars in play.yml playbook**

play.yml :

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  sudo: false

  vars:
    url: czxcxz

  tasks:
     - include: apache.yml
```

apache.yml :

```
- name: Download apache
  shell: wget {{url}}
```

**3. Make apache.yml complete playbook and import it in play.yml as playbook**

play.yml :

```
---
- name: Configure Apache
  import_playbook: apache.yml
```

apache.yml :

```
---
- name: Configure Apache
  hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  sudo: false

  vars:
    url: czxcxz

  tasks:
  - name: Download apache
    shell: wget {{url}}
```

**4. Import variables from separate file**

play.yml :

```
---
- hosts: localhost

  tasks:
  - include: apache.yml
```

apache.yml :

```
---
- name: Import apache vars
  # Static import var-file with single var look ugly
  include_vars: apache-vars.yml

- name: Download apache
  shell: wget {{ url }}
```

apache-vars.yml :

```
---
url: http://example.com/apache
```

**5. Consider put variables to host_var or group_var**

host_vars/localhost.yml :
or
host_vars/localhost/apache.yml :

```
---
url: http://example.com/apache
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have multiple tasks use a block instead

```
- name: Scope change (Kind of)
  block:
  - name: Download apache
    shell: wget {{ url }} 
  - name: Debug
    debug: 
      msg: "It ran: wget {{ url }}"
  vars:
      url: http://example.com/apache
```

In general, avoid using **set_fact** . If you do use it, its high precedence will override most other constructs including **vars:** .  It can cause very difficult to debug side effects, even outside the role, or include where it was used.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to have local variables that only persist through specific task, you can do this:

```
- name: My Task
  vars:
    my_var: 123
```

This can be useful, when you want to have more reusable roles, where it expects some generic variables (arguments). For example:

`my_debug_role/main.yml`:

```
- name: Output me
  ansible.builtin.debug:
    msg: "Your output was: {{ my_msg }}"
```

Then in your playbook, you can reuse it with more specific variable, like:

`my_playbook.yml`:

```
- name: Output my custom log
  include_role:
    name: my_debug_role
  vars:
    my_msg: "{{ some_custom_specific_variable }}"
```

Comment: For ansible 2.9.6 these approach
`- name: My Task
  vars:
    my_var: 123`
gives me an error:
`ERROR! no module/action detected in task.`

Answer (score -3):

Whenever you have a module followed by a variable on the same line in ansible the parser will treat the reference variable as the beginning of an in-line dictionary. For example:

```
- name: some example
  command: {{ myapp }} -a foo
```

The default here is to parse the first part of `{{ myapp }} -a foo` as a dictionary instead of a string and you will get an error.

So you must quote the argument like so:

```
- name: some example
  command: "{{ myapp }} -a foo"
```

Comment: This is true, but it doesn't answer the question.