# Ansible concatenate 2 files with jinja2 template

Tags: ansible, jinja2

I am trying to vertically concatenate 2 files

The 1st file is `roles/myrolename/files/requirements.dat`

```
numpy
matplotlib
dask
```

and the 2nd file is `~/myprojects/myprojectname/requirements.txt`

```
django
pywinrm
scipy
```

Here is my attempt to combine these 2 files, based on

- [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40761463/4057186)
- [the `include` jinja2 documentation](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/templates/#include)

Here is the [task](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27976496/4057186) I am using

```
- name: Play to combine 2 files
  hosts: localhost
  connection: local

  vars:
    myprojects_path: myprojects
    my_proj_name: myprojectname

  tasks:
    - name: Concatenate 2 files
      template:
        src: "roles/myrolename/templates/requirements.dat.j2"
        dest: "{{ myprojects_path }}/{{ my_proj_name }}/requirements.dat"
```

Here is `roles/myrolename/templates/requirements.dat.j2`

```
{% include 'roles/myrolename/files/requirements.dat' %}
{% include myprojects_path + "/" + my_proj_name + "/" + "requirements.txt" %}
```

This task gives the error message (related to the 2nd `include` statement from `roles/myrolename/templates/requirements.dat.j2`)

```
fatal: [my_local_machine]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, 
"msg": "TemplateNotFound: /home/wr/myprojects/myprojectname/requirements.txt"}
```

This seems to suggest that Ansible is expecting that `/home/wr/myprojects/myprojectname/requirements.txt` is a template and not a file. However, the first `include` line does not throw an error. This is confusing me.

Is there a way I can use `include` to concatenate these 2 files with the `jinja2` template, or is there another method to concatenate the 2 files?

**EDIT 1:**

I added `{# a comment #}` to the 1st line of `requirements.txt`. Here is the new `~/myprojects/myprojectname/requirements.txt`

```
{# a comment #}
django
pywinrm
scipy
```

Then, I re-ran the playbook `ansible-playbook test.yml -vvv`. Here is the output

```
<127.0.0.1> ESTABLISH LOCAL CONNECTION FOR USER: wr
<127.0.0.1> EXEC /bin/sh -c 'echo ~wr && sleep 0'
<127.0.0.1> EXEC /bin/sh -c '( umask 77 && mkdir -p "` echo /home/wr/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1532962816.77-184726406959930 `" && echo ansible-tmp-1532962816.77-184726406959930="` echo /home/wr/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1532962816.77-184726406959930 `" ) && sleep 0'
<127.0.0.1> EXEC /bin/sh -c 'rm -f -r /home/wr/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1532962816.77-184726406959930/ > /dev/null 2>&1 && sleep 0'
fatal: [wr-box]: FAILED! => {
    "changed": false, 
    "msg": "TemplateNotFound: /home/wr/myprojects/myprojectname/requirements.txt"
}
```

**EDIT 2:**

I tried to ask Ansible to treat the above `requirements.txt` (with `{# a comment #}` on 1st line) as a `jinja2` template by re-naming the file. I renamed the file `requirements.txt` to `requirements.txt.j2` and re-ran the playbook. It gives this output

```
<127.0.0.1> ESTABLISH LOCAL CONNECTION FOR USER: wr
<127.0.0.1> EXEC /bin/sh -c 'echo ~wr && sleep 0'
<127.0.0.1> EXEC /bin/sh -c '( umask 77 && mkdir -p "` echo /home/wr/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1532963056.03-76693523230507 `" && echo ansible-tmp-1532963056.03-76693523230507="` echo /home/wr/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1532963056.03-76693523230507 `" ) && sleep 0'
<127.0.0.1> EXEC /bin/sh -c 'rm -f -r /home/wr/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1532963056.03-76693523230507/ > /dev/null 2>&1 && sleep 0'
fatal: [wr-box]: FAILED! => {
    "changed": false, 
    "msg": "TemplateNotFound: /home/wr/myprojects/myprojectname/requirements.txt.j2"
}
```

It still does not seem to find the template file, even though I have checked that it is indeed present at the location I specified.

Comment: Have you tried to run in verbose mode to see if there is an hint how jinja was resolving the inclusion ? Have you tried to put a templating instruction in `requirement.txt` like `{# a comment #}`.

Comment: https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/7106#issuecomment-127825573

Comment: @techraf Thank you. My `requirements.txt` file was located outside the playbook directory. As your link suggests, this is not allowed so it was not detecting the `requirements.txt` as a template. This answers my question. I will create templates in `templates/` only and call them from there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Generally the [include](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/templates/#include) statement treats the file as a template. Also the file requirements.txt in your example is generally a template, without variables and with text only.

Does the file */home/wr/myprojects/myprojectname/requirements.txt* exist?

Comment: Yes, that file does exist. But, as you say, it is a text file without variables.